# Stored procedure called from C# doesn't update record

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have written a simple stored procedure for updating a record which isn't working but I can't work out why. No exceptions are thrown but the record doesn't update either.

See code below:

```
public int IMGId;

protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string result = "";
        string sSQL = "usp_imageloader_update";


        using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(CKS_app_settings.sql_conn_string_db))
        {
            // SqlTransaction tn=null;   
            try
            {
                dbConnection.Open();
                //start Transaction
                // tn = dbConnection.BeginTransaction();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sSQL, dbConnection);
                //command.Transaction = tn;
                command.CommandText = sSQL;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandTimeout = 1024;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_image_id", IMGId);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_url", txtUrl.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_alt_text", txtAlt.Text);
                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_filepath", File1.Value);
                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_cntr_id", str_id);
                int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
               // throw ex;

                //If it failed for whatever reason, rollback the //transaction
                //tn.Rollback();                          
                //No need to throw because we are at a top level call and //nothing is handling exceptions
                result = ex.InnerException.Message;
            }
        }
```

**Stored procedure in SQL SERVER**

```
USE [smsdb_test_griffin2]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_imageloader_update]    Script Date: 01/04/2012   09:05:41 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER    procedure [dbo].[usp_imageloader_update]
@p_image_id INT,
@p_url  VARCHAR(255),
@p_alt_text VARCHAR(255)
as 

UPDATE Image_Library_UK 
SET  
Url=@p_url,
Alt_text=@p_alt_text 

WHERE Image_id=@p_image_id
```

Comment: Does your SP work if you execute it in isolation, i.e. not from your C# code?

Comment: T-SQL you say? GO doesn't work in a stored procedure in T-SQL.

Comment: Have you tried exec procedure in SQL Managament with values passed in C#?

Comment: May be click handler of btnUpdate is reset/unset.

Comment: "UPDATE Image_Library_UK " updates table.

Comment: `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_image_id", IMGId);` From where Your `IMGId` comes From?

Comment: This may sound like a stupid question but how would I run it in isolation?

Comment: Right click on stored procedure and click execute in SQL Management Studio http://www.mssqltips.com/tipimages/1375_Execut1.jpg

Comment: When I click on execute it says "command completed successfully".

Comment: @nickgowdy and does the update work?

Comment: Can you check that the parameters being sent are correct? ie that your imgID actually is correct and exists in the table? And running it manualy should be as simple as connecting tot he database in management studio and running `EXEC usp_imageloader_update @p_image_id=1234, @p_url='newurl', @p_alt_text='Alt text'` (with the correct id and so on of course).

Comment: Have you tried catching generic exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having tried it in isolation, assuming that this works ( and there is nothing glaringly obvious wrong ), I would assume that one of your parameters is not being set correctly. It could be that the IMGid is not right - which would have this effect - or it coudl be that the the url and alttext have already be reset to their values by the load of the page.

Check the values at the point of calling. It may be you need to use !Page.IsPostBack to not reset these values on a postback. It may be that you need to access them using the request variable - it does depend on the rest of your code.

Comment: I hard coded an int value for the ID and the stored procedure worked. I guess something went wrong when grabbing the id from my code. Thanks to everyone that helped!